# Increment variable while storing information loop bash

Tags: bash, variables, while-loop, counter, increment

I need to increment `key` while also storing information. For example:

```
key1=value
key2=value
```

and so on...

```
count = 7

while [ $count -gt -1 ]
do
        key$count=${array[$count]}
        let count=$count-1
        echo $key
done
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? Smells like an XY-problem. Working with dynamically created variable names is almost always better done with arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `declare` directive here:

```
array=(10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90)

for ((count=7; count > -1; count--)); do
   declare "key$count"="${array[$count]}"
done
```